# Add already exists , php ldap add user

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I want to add a user to the active directory using ldap, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\GuestRegister\test3.php on line 41
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks :)

```
<?php
$ldaprdn  = "CN=HackTeam,CN=Users,DC=cisco,DC=internal";    
$ldappass = 'HackMe007';

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("10.33.85.172");


if ($ldapconn) {

// binding to ldap server
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

} else {
echo "Unable to connect to LDAP server";
}

$dn_user="CN=Dan Potts,CN=Users,DC=cisco,DC=internal";

$ldaprecord['cn'] = "Dan Potts";

$ldaprecord['sn'] = "Potts";
$ldaprecord['sAMAccountName'] = "danpotts";

$ldaprecord['name'] = "Dan Potts";
$ldaprecord['UserAccountControl'] = "66048";
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][0] = 'top';
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][1] = 'person';
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][2] = 'organizationalPerson';
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][2] = 'user';
$ldaprecord['mail'] = "danielpotts@cisco.com";

ldap_add($ldapconn, $dn_user, $ldaprecord);
ldap_unbind($ldapconn);  



?>
```

Comment: The error sounds pretty self explanatory to me

Answer (score 1):

(I know this is old, but)

the error means you're not properly connected to the LDAP server over SSL.  From my experience "Server is unwilling to perform" means you need to setup an SSL connection to your LDAP server/AD server to properly add users.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential problems.  One is that you're setting ['objectClass']['2'] twice.

The other is the `UserAccountControl` attribute.  You want NORMAL_ACCOUNT and DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD, but the password isn't set yet.  You probably need to create the account with specifying the `UserAccountControl` attribute, set the password, and then set the `UserAccountControl` attribute.